# Sqlsrv query doesn't show any result

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

`SELECT * FROM dbo.Warehouse` returns result, but when I change to `SELECT * FROM dbo.Accessories`, it neither shows any result nor echo 'Rows not found'. Both Warehouse and Accessories tables have rows. Here is my script.

```
<?php

require('db_connect.php');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Warehouse';
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);

if(!$stmt){
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}

$c = 0;
$result[] = array();
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt) != 0){
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $row = array($c => $row);
        $result[$c] = $row;
        $c++;
    }
} else {
   echo("Rows not found");
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Please help me, thanks in advance. :(

Comment: Use `'echo(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true))` to get the latest error from the code and please copy that error code here so that we can better help you.

Comment: Use a `do while` loop instead `while` loop and check if any error occurs for `$row`